# Vim matching everything except a character at the beginning of a line

Tags: regex, vim

I have extensively searched for an answer for this and I can't find it anywhere. I would like to replace all code in a function block with just one line(using search and replace) or some other command. I would also like to be able to do this for multiple functions throughout the entire file.

I have a block of code like this...

> {
>      some code
>      more code...
>      many lines of random code
>   }

I would like to replace everything inside the curly braces with one line of code such as:

> {
>      `return STATUS_OK;`
>   }

I tried something like,

> %s/^{_[^}]+/\treturn STATUS_OK;/g

but this stops at the first } rather than the first } at the beginning of a line.

I tried this

> %s/^{_[^^}]+/\treturn STATUS_OK;/g

in order to stop at the first } at the beginning of a line but this does not work for some reason. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex matches the outer most curlies without considering the function name:

```
 %s/^{\(\(\s\+}\)\|[^}]\|\_s\)*/{\treturn STATUS_OK;/g
```

Breakdown:

```
^{  # match a curly at the beginning of a line
\(  # group these alternations.... either match
     \(\s\+}\) \|  # whilespace followed by a closing curly 
                   # (to get rid of internal blocks) or ..
     [^}]      \|  # match a non curly, or ..
     \_s           # match newlines and whitespaces
 \)*               # match the alternation as long as you can
```

Comment: After adding \r before and after "\treturn STATUS_OK;" this works! Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind breaking this regex down for me? I want to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

is this (**macro**) ok for you:

```
qq/{<cr>ci{return STATUS_OK;<esc>q
```

then `99@q`

(**command line**)
if you love doing it with `:s`, you could try:

```
%s/^{\zs\_.\{-}\ze}/\rreturn STATUS_OK;\r/
```

your regex won't work, because here you need the "dot-all" (`\_.`)

**EDIT**

> The regex you posted still only matches to the first } and not the
>   first } at the beginning of a line.

I misunderstood your requirement. but modify the command to fit that is relatively easy:

```
%s/^{\zs\_.\{-}\ze\_^}/\rreturn foo;\r
```

this command will change:

```
asdfasf
{
some code
more code...
many lines of random code
     } (this is not the leading one)

{
some code
more code...
many lines of random code
}
```

into

```
asdfasf
{
return foo;
}
```

I hope it was what you are looking for.

Comment: I have never used macros before so I'll have to try that. The regex you posted still only matches to the first } and not the first } at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Your edit works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind explaining how this works? I understand the \zs and \ze represent the beginning and end of a pattern but what does {-} do?

Comment: `.\{-}` is same as pcrl's `.*?` (non-greedy) @sfurrow88

Answer (score 2):

Vim has a nice text object call "inner block" which is called by `iB` or `i{`. This text object represents a `{` and its matching `}`. So a block or in this case a function block.

Combine the `iB` text object with the `:global` and `:normal` command you can make short work of text change.

```
:g/{$/norm ciBreturn STATUS_OK;
```

Explanation

- `:g/{patter}/{cmd}` the global command, `:g`, will run a command, `{cmd}`, on ever line matching pattern, `{pat}`
- `:normal` or `:norm` for short, executes normal commands.

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :norm
:h iB
```

Comment: Dude that is pretty cool. Tried it out. Works great. How do you do a tab as part of the normal command? I tried \t but that didn't work.

Comment: You can insert the next typed key literally via `<c-v>` or `<c-q>`. So for a tab you press `<c-v><tab>`. Once done successfully you should get a funny looking `^I` symbol that represents your tab. See `:h i_ctrl-v`. You can think of this as "quoting", hence the `<c-q>` mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a macro:

1. yank in register "a" the text "return STATUS_OK"
2. find all {
3. start recording the macro
4. go to next {
5. vi{
6. paste the content of the register
7. repeat the macro

Answer (score 0):

It's a builtin.

```
/^{/
Vi{C
```

Find { at the start of a line you know, `V` is "visually select lines", `i{` is "inside braces", C you know.